# TypeLoadException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game and after loading assets and switching to the new Unity test version (2022.1.11f1) and then back (2021.3.6f1), I am now getting an error that pops up as follows:

> [Worker4] TypeLoadException: Could not load type UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.Antialiasing, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null while decoding custom attribute: (null)
> System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inheritedOnly) (at :0)
> System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at :0)
> System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.Rebuild () (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.FindCustomEditorTypeByType (System.Type type, System.Boolean multiEdit) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.FindCustomEditorType (UnityEngine.Object o, System.Boolean multiEdit) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.AssetPreviewUpdater.CreatePreview (UnityEngine.Object obj, UnityEngine.Object[] subAssets, System.String assetPath, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.AssetPreviewUpdater.CreatePreviewForAsset (UnityEngine.Object obj, UnityEngine.Object[] subAssets, System.String assetPath) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)

I am not sure what that is being caused by or what it is even affecting.  I have done a lot of the Unity courses and been working on the game for a couple months now, but this issue never came up.

Comment: 1) Close Unity 2) Delete the Library folder 3) Revert local source control changes 4) Open your project again in Unity.

Comment: How do I "revert local source control changes"?

Comment: Please refer to your source control system of choice.  You _are_ using source control?  If not skip step #3 above but beware by upgrading Unity, Unity _may_ have altered your code irreversibly.

Comment: I don't have a source control system, wasn't aware I needed one (or what they are/where to get them).  The method you suggested aside from step 3 seemed to work though.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  Unless you are just playing about, it's a good idea to setup source control first. e.g. Git.  It's great for performing an _undo._  Good luck! :)

Comment: Ah, are you referring to github?  I am familiar with that.  Or is it a different program?

Comment: Excellent.  Yes, GitHub is one place where you can store Git repositories.